# Как правильно: выстелет или выстелит?

Tags: глаголы, окончания

Как правильно: выстелет или выстелит?

Answer (score 3):

Если нужен один безусловно правильный вариант, то конечно, ***выстелет***. Эту форму дают как единственную почти все современные словари, как и для бесприставочного варианта "стелет".

Но если разбираться глубже, то, как это ни странно покажется, "выстелит" - не такая уж и ошибка.

История здесь такая. Исторически в русском языке существовал глагол "стлать". Этот глагол имел беглый корневой гласный и правильную парадигму первого (по современной школьной терминологии) спряжения: ***стлать - стелешь - стелет - стелют.***

Форма же "стелить" до недавнего времени считалась разговорной и даже просторечной, а порожденные ей формы второго спряжения - "стелишь", "стелит", "стелят" не использовались, поскольку фонетически неотличимы от форм первого спряжения (кроме, может, формы третьего лица множественного числа, но это отдельный разговор).

Со временем форма "стелить" приобрела бОльшие права и даже стала вытеснять форму "стлать". Но при этом орфография личных форм сохранилась. Этим и объясняется фиксация "стелить" в списке глаголов-исключений.

Надо сказать, что многие, если не все, такие исключения объясняются похожими обстоятельствами - грамматика и фонетика менялись с разной скоростью, - но именно пара стелить/стлать вызывает наибольшие затруднения в этом списке исключений. "Языковая память" носителей сопротивляется закрепленному грамматикой смешению наборов личных форм этой пары.

Поэтому лучше всего просто запомнить раз и навсегда, что в современном языке глагол "стелить" со всеми его производными изменяется по первому спряжению.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2):

Спрягается так же, как и глагол без приставки: *выстел**е**т.*